# Date picker in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-daterangepicker

Using angular datepicker, I cannot seem to get the selected date from the datepicker. When I select a date in the calendar it always sends the current date to the backend. Not the selected date.

This is the method that I implemented in TypeScript file.

```
getAttendanceForPeriod(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    this.apiService
      .getAttendanceForPeriod(startDate, endDate)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.dataSource = result.payload;
      });
  }
```

This is the method that I implemented in service file.

```
public getAttendanceForPeriod(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      '/attendance/get-attendance-for-period',
      {
        params: {
          startDate: startDate.toISOString(),
          endDate: endDate.toISOString(),
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

How can I get the correct date from the date picker?

Comment: Please show how you are using getAttendanceByPeriod.

Comment: Which date picker are you using? Is it the Material date picker (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)? Can you show how you are getting the date from the date picker?